# SelectItemsConverter do Omnifaces não reflete em telas os valores do objeto

Tags: java, jsf, framework

Estou usando o componente `selectOneMenu` com o converter do **omnifaces**. Quando eu salvo meu objeto no banco de dados funciona certinho, porém quando restauro as informações, elas não refletem na tela, ou seja, o componente `selectOneMenu` fica posicionado no primeiro item ou no item nulo.

Já confirmei com um *log* e um `inputText` de teste e as informações são carregadas corretamente. Estou usando o `selectItemsConverter` (tentei com o `SelectItemsIndexConverter` também) do **Omnifaces 1.8.3** (tentei a versão 1.10 também).

**AutomacaoEmail.java**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

...

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private ModeloEmail modeloEmail;

...

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 31 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.id);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final AutomacaoEmail other = (AutomacaoEmail) obj;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s[id=%d]", getClass().getSimpleName(), getId());
}
```

**loadFromDatabaseMethod()**

```
    List<ModeloEmail> modelosTemp = modeloEmailFacade.buscarTodos();
    SelectItemsBuilder selectItemsBuilder = new SelectItemsBuilder();
    if (modelosTemp != null) {
        for (ModeloEmail modeloEmail : modelosTemp) {
            selectItemsBuilder.add(modeloEmail, modeloEmail.getNome());
        }
        modelosEmails = selectItemsBuilder.buildList();
    }
```

**page.xhtml**

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{automacaoEmailsController.automacaoEmail.modeloEmail}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
    <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="Selecionar um modelo"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{automacaoEmailsController.modelosEmails}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```